# Android : Detect movement of eyes using sensor at real time

Tags: android, background, android-camera, face-detection, proximitysensor

I am preparing one android application in which I have to detect to movement of eyes. Somehow I am able to achieve the above thing on images but I want this on live eyes.

I am not able to understand that if we can use the proximity sensor to detect the eyes. Just like smartStay feature.

Please suggest the ideas to implement the same.

Comment: you'll not use proximity for that, you'll use your cam... i hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @OmarElDon for suggestion. So front camera won't get appear on screen at background it will detect the eyes. Please confirm if my understanding is correct.

Comment: not exactly, it's just proximity can't work as a movement detector at least for far object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the front camera to detect the eyes and eyes blink. Use the Vision api for detecting the eyes.

Code for eye tracking:

```
public class FaceTracker extends Tracker<Face> {

private static final float PROB_THRESHOLD = 0.7f;
private static final String TAG = FaceTracker.class.getSimpleName();
private boolean leftClosed;
private boolean rightClosed;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Detector.Detections<Face> detections, Face face) {
    if (leftClosed && face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability() > PROB_THRESHOLD) {
        leftClosed = false;
    } else if (!leftClosed &&  face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability() < PROB_THRESHOLD){
        leftClosed = true;
    }
    if (rightClosed && face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability() > PROB_THRESHOLD) {
        rightClosed = false;
    } else if (!rightClosed && face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability() < PROB_THRESHOLD) {
        rightClosed = true;
    }

    if (leftClosed && !rightClosed) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new LeftEyeClosedEvent());
    } else if (rightClosed && !leftClosed) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new RightEyeClosedEvent());
    } else if (!leftClosed && !rightClosed) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new NeutralFaceEvent());
    }
}
}


//method to call the FaceTracker 
 private void createCameraResources() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    // create and setup the face detector
    mFaceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setProminentFaceOnly(true) // optimize for single, relatively large face
            .setTrackingEnabled(true) // enable face tracking
            .setClassificationType(/* eyes open and smile */ FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE) // for one face this is OK
            .build();

    // now that we've got a detector, create a processor pipeline to receive the detection
    // results
    mFaceDetector.setProcessor(new LargestFaceFocusingProcessor(mFaceDetector, new FaceTracker()));

    // operational...?
    if (!mFaceDetector.isOperational()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "createCameraResources: detector NOT operational");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "createCameraResources: detector operational");
    }

    // Create camera source that will capture video frames
    // Use the front camera
    mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, mFaceDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .setRequestedFps(30f)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use proximity sensor for eye detection or tracking . Give a shot to OpenCV .
Link : [OpenCv](http://romanhosek.cz/android-eye-detection-and-tracking-with-opencv/)
github : [OpenCv github](https://github.com/crankdaworld/Android-OpenCV-FaceDetectionwithEyes/blob/master/OpenCV-Android-FaceDetect-Eye/FdEye/src/org/opencv/samples/fd/FdView.java)

Comment: can we use Front Camera for eye detection? Means front cam can run in background and is able to sense the eyes.

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: do you have any running example for this on android without openCv(don't know anything about openCv).